# KSQL REST API does not take time to respond

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I am facing issue in calling KSQL Rest endpoint to execute query, my query is :

select * from stream1 where is = 123 limit 3;

i send it in the body of the post request as follow:

> { "ksql": "SELECT * FROM stream1 where id =
>   3 LIMIT 3; ", "streamsProperties":
>   {"ksql.streams.auto.offset.reset": "earliest"} }

some times it respond in 1 seconds and some times it respond in 5 seconds and some time in 10 seconds.

There is big size data in the stream just couple of messages;

is there any way to fix this issue or we need to use postgress, mysql .. to solve this.

Comment: How many messages do you have on your source topic? Do you see the same variance in response time if you run the query from the KSQL CLI?

Comment: topic has 100 messages and in the KSQL CLI response time is always 1-2 seconds but the problem in using KSQL Rest endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

The rest endpoint in the version of ksql you're used was not intended to be used as a way of querying streams and tables from an application tier. It was primarily designed for use by humans by way of the CLI.

For this reason, it is not optimised for the type of operations you're trying to execute.

The next release of ksqlDB, (0.10.x), will come with a new client API, which may allow you to do what you want.